# особый вид дополнение файла

Tags: c++, файлы

При работе с файлом я использую класс `fstream`. Допустим, в файле записано "hello, world", и позиция файлового указателя на ',' . При записи в файл методом `write` строки "0TTT0" файл будет иметь содержимое "hello0TTT0ld". Как сделать чтобы символы , которые справа от указателя перемещались, то есть файл имел содержимое "hello0TTT0, world" ?

Comment: Прочитать хвост, записать вашу вставку, записать ранее прочитанный хвост.

Answer (score 6):

Никак.

Файл аналогичен массиву байт, то, что вы пишете в него, затирает контент, который уже там находится.

Как решить вашу задачу проще всего — это считать всё содержимое в память, зарезервировать больше места, скопировать «хвост» в добавленное место, и вставить новые данные. И записать назад в файл.

Для этого лучше, вероятно, воспользоваться строкой/набором строк: в них есть уже готовая процедура вставки в середину (которая делает именно то, что описано выше).